# How to group a Seq[Array[(Int, Int)]]) by the second value of array

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of `Seq[(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1)]`

I would like to modify it to `Seq[(1,2,2),(1,1,2)]` grouped by the second value

of each map in the array.

I have tried `.groupBy(_._2)` but it doesn't work. It gives me

```
value _2 is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Array[(Int,Int)]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
val input = Seq((1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1))
input.groupBy(_._2).collect{
  case e => e._2.map(_._1)
}
//res3: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `scala.collection.immutable.Array[(Int, Int)]` you just need to select the second value for group and select only first values

```
data.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(x => x.map(_._1)).map(_._2).toList
```

This will give you `List[Array[Int]]`

Hope this helps!