# Scala lists processing

Tags: scala

I wrote the following code

```
val listInput=List("banana  10 10 rr", 
  "apple   20  10 rr",
  "apple   30  10 rr",
  "banana   10 10 rr",
  "berry    10  10 rr")

val result = listInput.map(_.split("\\s+")).groupBy(e=> e.apply(0)).collect{
  case e=> (e._1, e._2.map(_.apply(1).toInt).sum, e._2.map(_.apply(2).toInt).sum,e._2.map(._3)}
```

I am getting an error
Actually, the wanted result shall be:

```
val listoutput=List("banana  20 20 rr",    
  "apple   50  20 rr",      
  "berry    10  10 rr")
```

My problem is that I can not access the rr element of each line.

Comment: What is this `(._3)` thing supposed to be? Some parentheses seem to be missing.

Comment: I don't know how ta access the 3rd element of list of array of strings , I am a beginner in scala , sorry ^^

Comment: What's supposed to happen if `e.map(_(3))` turns out to be not of the shape `List(rr, rr, rr, ..., rr)`, but instead something like `List(rr, rr2, rr3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here:

```
val listInput = List(
  "banana  10 10 rr",
  "apple   20  10 rr",
  "apple   30  10 rr",
  "banana   10 10 rr",
  "berry    10  10 rr"
)

val result = listInput
  .map(_.split("\\s+"))
  .groupBy(_(0))
  .map{ case (label, listOfArrays) => 
     "%s %d %d %s".format(
       label,
       listOfArrays.map(_(1).toInt).sum,
       listOfArrays.map(_(2).toInt).sum,
       listOfArrays.head.apply(3)
     )
  }

println(result)
```

produces:

```
List(banana 20 20 rr, apple 50 20 rr, berry 10 10 rr)
```

Explanation:

- `_.split(...)` converts strings into arrays of substrings
- `groupBy(_(0))` groups the arrays by the first substring (label "apple" etc.)
- The `map` works on key-value pairs produced by `groupBy`, the labels ("apple" etc) are the keys, lists of arrays are values.
- Pattern matching `case (label, listOfArrays) => ...` is used to extract keys and values
- `listOfArrays.map(_(i).toInt).sum` extracts `i`-th component from each array, and then computes the total sum of those components.
- Labels and total sums are combined into a single string again using `String.format` with pattern `"%s %d %d %s"`, which stands for "string decimal decimal string".

Most common errors in your code:

- `i`-th element of an array `a` is accessed as `a(i)`, no need to write out the `a.apply(i)` explicitly
- `i`-th element of an array is *not* accessed by `_i`
- After a `groupBy`, you obtain a map. A map is essentially a collection of key-value pairs. A key-value pair has elements `_1` and `_2`, but not `_3`.
- `collect` is not necessary if every entry matches. Use `map` instead (it's exactly the same problem that I've pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288893/how-to-group-a-seqarrayint-int-by-the-second-value-of-array/50301273#50301273) just few days ago).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a `case class` to make the readability a bit better. and `scalaz` also provides a function `|+|` to add tuples directly. Here is the sample code.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
val listInput=List("banana 10 10 rr",
  "apple   20  10 rr",
  "apple   30  10 rr",
  "banana   10 10 rr",
  "berry    10  10 rr")


case class Foo(name:String, value1:Int, value2:Int, tag:String){
  override def toString = s"${name} ${value1} ${value2} ${tag}"
}
listInput
.map(_.split("\\s+").toList)
.map{
  case a::b::c::d::Nil =>
  Foo(a, b.toInt, c.toInt, d)
}
.groupBy(x => (x.name, x.tag))
.map{
  case ((n, t), y) =>
  val (v1, v2) = y.map(s => (s.value1, s.value2)).reduce(_|+|_)
  Foo(name = n, tag = t, value1 = v1, value2 = v2)
}.map(_.toString)
```